# How do I assign the resolved value of a .then to a variable?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise called `goodNight` and I am trying to chain it to a `.then()` that will assign the resolved value to a variable called `night`. I am having trouble figuring this out and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

`var night = "";`

Here is what I am trying:

```
goodNight.then(function(night) {
    return Promise.resolve(night)
})
```

Comment: Please post more code.  I'm pretty sure you're trying to assign to a variable outside of the Promise chain, but there isn't enough code here to say for certain.

Comment: @zero298 The only code I am given to work with is `var night = "";` I am to just assume the promise `goodNight` already exists.

Comment: Is this an assignment or live code?

Comment: @zero298 An assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the data passed down from the callback to the `night` variable.

```
var night;

goodNight.then(function(data) {
   night = data;
});
```

Comment: This did it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this.  The very next thing that is going to happen is the OP is going to ask why `night` is `undefined` when they `console()` it right below the `.then()`.

Comment: @zero298 What would you suggest?